# Issue with jolt transform with other language

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I have an input JSON that has some Japanese characters and when using Jolt to transform it, it gives ? in the output JSON.

Input JOSN

```
[
  {
    "日付": 20230420,
    "個数": 1,
    "便名": "例"
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```
[ 
  {
    "OrderDate" : 20230420,
    "Quantity" : 1,
    "Carrier" : "例"
  } 
]
```

Current output

```
[
  {
    "OrderDate": 20230420,
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Carrier": "?"
  }
]
```

Current transform specs

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "日付": "[&1].OrderDate",
        "個数": "[&1].Quantity",
        "便名": "[&1].Carrier"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to get the exact character in the third field but I am unable to get this.
Can anybody help with this?

NOTE: This behavior is observed in Jolt Demo website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what platform do you need to use? It works if Apache NiFi is the case, at least for version 1.19 I observe this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works perfectly in Apache Nifi.
I observed this behavior on the Jolt demo website while I was testing for this input.